# Is it possible to hibernate in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Mac OS X support hibernation?](https://superuser.com/questions/59188/does-mac-os-x-support-hibernation)

Is it possible to hibernate a Mac? And if so is it safe to remove the power from the computer when it is hibernated?

Comment: But the Question is "Suppose I am using iMac. I press sleep, Now, Can I disconnect all power supplies to iMac?"

Comment: More details in http://superuser.com/questions/59188/does-mac-os-x-support-hibernation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple prefers using a power-efficient sleep state rather than hibernating.

When you close the lid of an Apple laptop, press the power button and choose Sleep, or use "Sleep" from the Apple menu, it enters a sleep state that is very power efficient.  I can leave my laptop in sleep mode for days without losing a significant amount of battery.  It also turns back on ready to work in about 1 second.

[Macs newer than about October 2005 use Safe Sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28OS_feature%29#Mac_OS), which saves data stored in RAM to the hard disk as well.  This is what happens when you hibernate a PC.  If your computer loses power while it is sleeping, it will restore RAM contents from disk.

Comment: But the Question is "Suppose I am using iMac. I press sleep, Now, Can I disconnect all power supplies to iMac?"

Comment: If the iMac is newer than October 2005, yes. Safe Sleep allows this. I've edited my answer to include this.