# Do not wakeup Mac on mouse movements

Tags: mac, energy-saving

I never switch off my mac in the office, instead i use the energy saving mode to suspend the mac to disc. This is all working fine, but I have one problem: when the cleaning lady is cleaning the office, she also moves the mouse and the mac wakes up.

Can I set the energy save to not to wake up on mouse movements?

Comment: You could [configure](http://superuser.com/questions/59188/does-mac-os-x-support-hibernation) your Mac to go into hibernation ("safe sleep") instead of standby, I think it won't wake from USB in that case.

Comment: But I want the mac to wake up on keyboard entry not only when I press the power button :( .

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: My solution at the moment: unplug the mouse from the keyboard, plug the mouse in every day.

Comment: You could get a cordless mouse that has a shut-off switch on the bottom; mouse movement then won't be a factor.

Comment: Apples Bluetooth Mighty Mouse will go into hibernation if it looses connection to the computer and will only wake a computer if you press the button, not on movement alone. Switching it off completely will prevent that as well obviously. Other manufacturers may differ.

Comment: Is there still no solution here for a USB mouse (NOT bluetooth)?? These are easy power options in both Windows and Linux and I'm frustrated that I can't do the same with my iMac! I don't want to hibernate it, I keep it sleeping because it only uses 1.2 watts when sleeping and it wakes quickly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to System Preferences » Bluetooth » Advanced and turn off "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer."

To wake the computer, you'll have to press the power button.

I do this because my iMac wakes itself up in the middle of the night.

Comment: Doesn't work for non-bluetooth devices.

Comment: 10 years later, Big Sur currently and settings are still relevant.

Comment: I don't have that option there. Hope Monterey didn't kill it.

Comment: I don't see that option anymore either

Answer (score 7):

Kind of a dumb answer but whenever you step away from the desk you can flip the mouse upside down.

Comment: You could, but the cleaning lady might think it's dead and throw it out.

Comment: I tried that a few weeks ago, but the cleaning lady thought this was by accident and fliped the mouse back.

Comment: Ok, the very last comment on this page makes it sound like any of these 3 apps will put a mac into a deeper sleep, so that it requires either more mouse movement to wake it, or some other wake method. I never tried any of them but might as well try them, all are free. http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=22132

Comment: Just a though... and more of an "in real life" hack... but could you ask the cleaning lady to leave the mouse upside down?

Comment: or drop the mouse into a desk drawer - if she's going in there you've got a larger problem

Comment: I can't believe Tim Apple thinks disallowing this settings is fine ux. @creeDorofl thanks for the smart solution here

Answer (score 1):

I pull the mouse and keyboard usbs out slightly before the room gets cleaned, I just push them back in to turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you without a bluetooth mouse you can put sticky tack over the laser and it won't wake up. Easy to remove and doesn't leave residue.

Answer (score 1):

Most bluetooth mice of which I am familiar have a power switch on the bottom to save battery.  If yours does, I suggest just turning off the mouse at night and back on the next day.